# How do I list an indefinite number of nested categories and subcategories with a partial view.(.NET CORE 5.0)

Tags: .net-core, nested-loops, razor-pages, partial-views

I am new to programming. I want to list the categories whose nested number is not clear. As a result of my research, I decided that I could do it in a single Database table. I thought I should use a recursive structure for this and decided to use partialview for it.

DB Entity

```
public class Categories {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentCatID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Instruction { get; set; }
}
```

PartialView I am trying to write

[image]

Can I do it without using PartialView?

I want to achieve this output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class

```
public class Categories
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCatID { get; set; }

    public Categories ParentCat { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string Instruction { get; set; }

    public IList<Categories> Children { get; protected set; } = new List<Categories>();
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class CategoriesViewModel
{
    public CategoriesViewModel()
    {
        ChildItems = new List<CategoriesViewModel>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string Instruction { get; set; }

    public CategoriesViewModel ParentCatID { get; set; }

    public IList<CategoriesViewModel> ChildItems { get; set; }

    public void AddChildItem(CategoriesViewModel childItem)
    {
        childItem.ParentCatID = this;
        ChildItems.Add(childItem);
    }
}
```

controller

```
public IActionResult List()
{
    var categories = _context.ToList(); // example

    var categoryItems = new List<CategoriesViewModel>();

    var topCategories = categories.Where(x => !x.ParentCatID.HasValue);
    foreach (var category in topCategories)
    {
        var categoryMenuItem = Map(category);
        categoryItems.Add(categoryMenuItem);
    }

    return View(categoryItems);
}

private CategoriesViewModel Map(Categories category)
{
    var categoryMenuItem = new CategoriesViewModel
    {
        ID = category.ID,
        CategoryName = category.CategoryName,
        Instruction = category.Instruction
    };

    var childCategories = category.Children;
    foreach (var childCategory in childCategories)
    {
        var childCategoryMenuItem = Map(childCategory);
        categoryMenuItem.AddChildItem(childCategoryMenuItem);
    }

    return categoryMenuItem;
}
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel> 
    
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.ChildItems.Any())
    {
        <li>
            <span>@item.CategoryName</span>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li>
                    @foreach (var childItem in item.ChildItems)
                    {
                        <span>@childItem.CategoryName</span>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li><span>@item.CategoryName</span></li>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it Partial View you mean View?

Comment: partial view değil. view.

Comment: Teşekkür ederim . Model de neden Categories adında tekrardan bir property oluşturuyoruz. Onu araştırmam için bana bir keyword söyler misin ? Mantığı ne?

Comment: Aynı property tekrardan kullanabilmek için birbirine bağlıyorsun. Tabi farklı tablo property kullanmak istersen onuda bağlayabilirsin.